# getTag = null pointer

Tags: android

I keep getting null pointer for this part of the code.

```
private OnClickListener fButton = new OnClickListener() {
     public void onClick(View v) {
         Intent myIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
         int intID = (Integer) v.getTag();
         String finalUrl = mInfo.get(intID).final_url;
         myIntent.setData(Uri.parse(finalUrl));
         startActivity(myIntent);

     }
};
```

Comment: Did you set fButton.setTag(intId)  ?

Comment: Can you please add the stacktrace?

Comment: @GilMoshayof v can not be null, since is the argument of onClick

Comment: sorry for not being clear, Gil Moshayof is correct. I am getting null pointer exception from this line to be exact:

int intID = (Integer) v.getTag();

Comment: Did you set tag before calling getTag?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

it is for the auto boxing/unboxing java feature. The object you are casting to object is accessed to retrieve the int value, in this case, trough `integerInstance.intValue()`. If you forgot to set tag, the returned value will be null, causing a NPE.

You should check for null values.

```
int intID = (v.getTag() == null) ? -1 : (Integer) v.getTag();
```

Comment: U are right i forgot to set the tag to the button. Wish i could have 2 correct answer to blackbelt and deacoy

Answer (score 0):

Try to set `yourView.setTag()` before get `yourView.getTag()`.