# Using button.getTag() causes the app to Crash

Tags: java, android

whenever I try to get .tag() My App Crashes. It's been a while and , i can't solve the problem....

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    public void translateFrench(View view){

        Button button = (Button) view;

        Log.i("Nothing", button.getTag().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }
}
```

XML:

```
<android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout
    android:layout_width="368dp"
    android:layout_height="495dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="8dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:columnCount="2"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:rowCount="4">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button1"
        android:text="Do you speak \nEnglish?"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="translateFrench"/>

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button2"
        android:text="Good Evening"
        app:layout_columnWeight="1"
        app:layout_gravity="fill"
        app:layout_rowWeight="1"
        android:onClick="translateFrench"/>

 </android.support.v7.widget.GridLayout>
```

Error Log:

Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.lang.Object.toString()' on a null object reference
        at

Comment: where u call translateFrench()  ???

Comment: It is onClick method.. For buttons.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and post error log

Comment: share the code of on click, point where you are calling translateFrench. I have a feeling you are sending the wrong view

Comment: You should include logcat info as well, it is not helpful for putting only your code

Comment: You should use setTag method before calling getTag. Please make sure that you care doing that.

Comment: where are you setting the tag of a button?

Comment: as Sudhi wrote you need to cal setTag() before getTag

Comment: Also shouldn't it be `buttonPressed.getTag()` ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [getTag = null pointer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24447318/gettag-null-pointer)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to call setTag() before getTag()
I think you can find useful information at this post

[What is the main purpose of setTag() getTag() methods of View?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5291726/what-is-the-main-purpose-of-settag-gettag-methods-of-view)

Comment: Do  I have to add Tags in xml for each of the buttons..? Or I can do it inside the java part. I'm extremely new in this.

Comment: Do it inside java part